# $wpdb->prepare not working with update table prefix

Tags: wpdb

The following does not work with my custom table:

```
$wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $wpdb->jch_gigs 
SET available = available - %d 
WHERE ID = %d", $quantity, $item) );
```

But this does:

```
$wpdb->prepare( "UPDATE jch_gigs 
SET available = available - %d 
WHERE ID = %d", $quantity, $item) );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is likely that `$wpdb->jch_gigs` is undefined. Is `jch_` the prefix of your DB tables, as defined in `wp-config.php`? If so, try this:

```
$wpdb->prepare( 
    "UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}gigs 
    SET available = available - %d 
    WHERE ID = %d",
     $quantity, 
     $item ) 
);
```

[`wpdb` class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) on the Codex